# passing a number variable to index() or eq()

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm trying to do this:

```
$('li').eq(newCurrent).addClass('current');
```

I've tried index() as well but I'm certainly missing something. I'm passing the 'newCurrent' variable, which is a list item a user has clicked on, as an argument to a function of which this is the last statement.

alerting just before verifies that "newCurrent" is the appropriate number/indice of the unordered list that I want to address.

I played with multiple selectors using .add but nope... I'm stuck?

Comment: That seems right. Can you post some more code

Comment: What is `newCurrent` and where does it come from?  Is it a string or a number or an element or a jQuery object?

Comment: just ran into this problem, I can't get eq() in either form to accept anything other than an explicit int (1) any stored variable parsed as an int number or anything doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do this

```
$('li:eq('+newCurrent+')').addClass('current');
```

Comment: Assuming `newCurrent` is a number, this is no different result than what the OP already has.

Comment: @jfriend00: This might work around the problem if `newCurrent` is a string, because it will get appended into another string, and then parsed by jQuery as an integer.  It doesn't really get to the root of the issue, but might resolve the symptom.

Comment: Well then perhaps you should add little explanation in your answer as to why your solution might solve the problem.  If `newCurrent` is a number already, this does not do anything different.

Comment: It wasn't my answer.  I was just pontificating on why this might solve the problem.  I agree with what you are saying.

Comment: ok sweet! that worked. @jeff b I gave point because I like that thinking...though in this case it was an integer, thanks!

Comment: @kellyjohnson: It was an actual integer and not an integer in a string?  I find that difficult to believe, but then again, you didn't provide your code for `newCurrent`, so I am just guessing.

Comment: If this solved the problem, then newCurrent was not a number, it must have been a string.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that `newCurrent` is a string?  If so, you need to convert it to an integer:

```
$('li').eq( parseInt(newCurrent, 10) ).addClass('current');
```

`parseInt(newCurrent, 10)` will convert a numeric string to a decimal integer.